# Youtube: Error authenticating (check service name)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've created a Gmail account and linked it with Youtube.
I can sign in using the credentials on Youtube site,
but I'm getting this error when I use the data API

**Exception:**

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)
```

**Code:**

```
 YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("", messages.get("youtube.devkey"));
        try {
            service.setUserCredentials("XXXXan@gmail.com", "alXXXX23");
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or what the service name is?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post for a list of reasons why ClientLogin might not succeed: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html

Answer (score 1):

Moving my comment to a formal answer, since it seemed to have solved the problem:

There's a list of common reasons why ClientLogin might fail and suggested alternatives at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html

Comment: Could you copy over the answer here? The link no longer contains it.

Comment: ClientLogin has been deprecated, so the answer is no longer relevant.